# Pixels at arrow tip missing when using antialiasing

Tags: c++, opencv, line, antialiasing

I am trying to draw an arrow with OpenCV 3.2:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  Mat image(480, 640, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255, 255, 255)); //White background
  Point from(320, 240); //Middle
  Point to(639, 240); //Right border
  arrowedLine(image, from, to, Vec3b(0, 0, 0), 1, LINE_AA, 0, 0.1);
  imshow("Arrow", image);
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

An arrow is drawn, but at the tip some pixels are missing:

[image: Arrow with missing tip pixels]

To be more precise, two columns of pixels are not colored correctly (zoomed):

[image]

If I disable antialiasing, i.e., if I use

```
arrowedLine(image, from, to, Vec3b(0, 0, 0), 1, LINE_8, 0, 0.1);
```

instead (note the LINE_8 instead of LINE_AA), the pixels are there, albeit without antialiasing:

[image]

I am aware that antialiasing might rely on neighboring pixels, but it seems strange that pixels are not drawn at all at the borders instead of being drawn without antialiasing. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Increasing the X coordinate, e.g. to 640 or 641) makes the problem worse, i.e., more of the arrow head pixels disappear, while the tip still lacks nearly two complete pixel columns.

Extending and cropping the image would solve the neighboring pixels issue, but in my original use case, where the problem appeared, I cannot enlarge my image, i.e., its size must remain constant.

Comment: you can have average of "before" and "after" at the borders

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Do you mean I draw the arrow with and without AA and take the average in the two affected columns?

Comment: I mean only borders, not whole image

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: I don't understand. Can you give an example?

Comment: point from 0,0 to 0,x, point from 0,x to y,x

Comment: I think the problem is that you are drawing independent lines, which are no aware of the existence of other lines. Depending on the AA algorithm that's the expected behaviour. You can try to detect the AA flag and modify the starting and ending points to avoid it.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Could you be more precise, please? What are x and y in your example? The tip coordinates?

Comment: @cbuchart: But I am only using one function call in the MWE above (`drawArrow`). Or do you mean that OpenCV just draws three independent lines? How would I modify the points exactly? The tip should touch the edge of the image, but I am already passing the largest meaningful X coordinate above.

Answer (score 3):

After a quick review, I've found that OpenCV [draws AA lines using a Gaussian filter](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line), which *contracts* the final image.

As I've suggested in comments, you can implement your own function for the AA mode (you can call the original one if AA is disabled) extending the points manually (see code below to have an idea).

Other option may be to increase the line width when using AA.

You may also simulate the AA effect of OpenCV but on the final image (may be slower but helpful if you have many arrows). I'm not an OpenCV expert so I'll write a general scheme:

```
// Filter radius, the higher the stronger
const int kRadius = 3;

// Image is extended to fit pixels that are not going to be blurred
Mat blurred(480 + kRadius * 2, 640 + kRadius * 2, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255, 255, 255));

// Points moved a according to filter radius (need testing, but the idea is that)
Point from(320, 240 + kRadius);
Point to(639 + kRadius * 2, 240 + kRadius);

// Extended non-AA arrow
arrowedLine(blurred, ..., LINE_8, ...);

// Simulate AA
GaussianBlur(blurred, blurred, Size(kRadius, kRadius), ...);

// Crop image (be careful, it doesn't copy data)
Mat image = blurred(Rect(kRadius, kRadius, 640, 480));
```

Another option may be to draw the arrow in an image twice as large and the scale it down with a good smoothing filter.

Obviously, last two options will work only if you don't have any previous data on the image. If so, then use a transparent image for temporal drawing and overlay it at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and the effort, but this would require reallocating the original image, i.e., effectively moving it in memory, correct?

Comment: If you are manually performing the blur passing  `BORDER_REPLICATE` to GaussianBlur should give better results. With this flag it will pick the color of the line in the last column.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that option, great!

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced: That's really nice. I suppose that there is no chance to get `drawArrow` to do this as well? It seems like a bug to me as it behaves currently at borders of pictures.